# Reducing the training time of an RL agent

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, policy-gradients, dynamic-programming

I am trying to develop an rl agent using DQN algorithm.During training, the agent interacts with environment which is a simulated one.Each episode takes around 10 mins to run. This way if want my agent to train for some 1000000(to achieve convergence) episodes, its becoming computationally infeasible, Is there a way anyone is aware to speed up my training process, like using parallel threading or using cuda. Or is it something because of the algorithm?

my episode here basically is of a one day long with actions taken at every 15 mins. I am using FMIs for the simulation and to finish this 1 episode it takes 10 mins. I can reduce my episode time to few seconds by using reduced order models/equations. This decreases the episode length(time). But my question is are there ways to speed up the training process. Or there better algorithms than DQN which donot reqire this much of training.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, my episode here basically is of a one day long with actions taken at every 15 mins. I am using FMIs for the simulation and to finish this 1 episode it takes 10  mins. I can reduce my episode time to few seconds by using reduced order models/equations. This decreases the episode length(time). But my question is are there ways to speed up the training process. Or there better algorithms than DQN which donot reqire this much of training. Thanks

Comment: You suggest that you might want to run for 10,000,000 episodes, but do not say where you got this estimate from or why you think you need this many. If you really are looking for ways to reduce amount of data, the more formal term for this is "sample efficiency". For ideas to improve sample efficiency, someone answering would need to know what variants of DQN you are already using, some key facts about your environment (e.g. is it stochastic, what is the variance in return from a deterministic policy, state and action space size), and ideally some indication of your current sample efficiency

Comment: sorry for not making it clear, editing the question accordingly

Comment: @NeilSlater. thank you.  is there a way i can speed up the training process with same amount of data?

Comment: That's a little bit clearer. But using the phrases "speed up" and "reduce the time" still makes it look like you are asking about the *clock time* it takes to train using DQN. Whilst what you actually seem to care about is the *number of episodes* that you must simulate before you can get an approximate optimal policy. And that's because your simulations are computationally expensive (looks like orders of magnitude more compute required for the simulation than any neural network training time on the produced data)

Comment: You have put it correctly. But also ,I am interested in knowing if there are ways we can reduce the clock time it takes to train using DQN?

Comment: Could you give some information about your resources? Slow training and fast training is quite ambiguous. You are also mentioning about a simulator. Are you training the DQN with the simulator? Have you checked if the simulator with the DQN are using tcp-ip ports? GPU(s), multi-core CPU of course they will help but there is more information needed here. What about the task?